# Confirm dialog before exit android studio

Tags: java, android

Hi guys I have an exit button on my main activity XML however I need it so when the user clicks it, it opens a dialogue to confirm the exit, if yes then exit. if no take them back.

here's my code so far, don't have any of that part however as I don't know where to start.

```
package com.tradingsoftwarelimited.labelprinter10;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    //Sets Edit and Data Button to hidden
    Button hiddenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
    hiddenButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Button hiddenButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dataButton);
    hiddenButton1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Acknolages settings button
    Button showButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);

    //if clicked
    showButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //If clicked show Edit and data Button
            Button showButton = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.editButton));
            showButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Button showButton1 = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.dataButton));
            showButton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    });

}




    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        return true;
        }
    };


;
```

Comment: you can use direct method in main activity is onBackPressed(), So when user presses back then you can display one alert with two button 1.Exit, 2.Cancel, If user presses Exit close the application else doNothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private void confirmDialog(Context context){ 

   final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    new ContextThemeWrapper(context,android.R.style.Theme_Dialog))
                    .create();
            alert.setTitle("Alert");
            alert.setMessage("Do you want to exit ?");
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            alert.dismiss();

                            finish();

                        }
                    });

            alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            alert.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

            alert.show();
}
```

Call this method in

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        confirmDialog(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

of your `Activity`

Comment: Thank you how do I make my button interlink with this?

Comment: Thank you how do I make my button interlink with this? it also sayes {context} cannot be resolved?

Comment: @StevenMarshall Put the code snippet simply in your Activity class

Comment: Ive done that now it sayes cannot resolve confirmDialog method and the context can still not be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 Button exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
exitButton..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
AlertDialog.Builder builde = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builde.setMessage(
                "Want Exit?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes ", dialogClickListeners)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", dialogClickListeners).show();
}
        });

DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListeners = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            switch (which) 
            {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
finish();
            break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:

            break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



Invite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);

    final DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListeners = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            finish();
                            break;
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:

                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
            Invite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builde = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builde.setMessage(
                            "Want Exit?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes ", dialogClickListeners)
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", dialogClickListeners).show();
                }
            });

        }
```